# prevent the user from being able to add names

Tags: reactjs

I need to prevent the user from being able to add names that already exist in the person list but I'm not sure where should I add it and also what method is better to use .includes or indexOf? I want issue a warning with the alert command when such an action is attempted. Any help would be much appropriated!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([  { name: 'Arto Hellas' }]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')

  const addName = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const nameObject = {
          name: newName,
      }
      setPersons([...persons,nameObject])
  }

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
      setNewName(event.target.value)
  }
 

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName} >
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
        {persons.map(person => (
            <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
        ))}
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Neither of those array methods accept a callback, making it impossible (as far as I know) to use it to check for existence based on an object property. I would suggest looking into [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something in the following place:

```js
  const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName
    };
    setPersons([...persons, nameObject]);
  };
```

Use `.find()` on the `persons` array to find the particular name already existing and add the condition before `setPersons` is executed.

```
if (persons.find(p => p.name === newName)) {
  window.alert("Name already exists!");
  return false;
}
```

A code like above will work.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([{ name: "Arto Hellas" }]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");

  const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (persons.find((p) => p.name === newName)) {
      window.alert("Name already exists!");
      return false;
    }
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName
    };
    setPersons([...persons, nameObject]);
  };

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setNewName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName}>
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {persons.map((person) => (
        <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-poitras-i3stw?file=/src/App.js:0-958**

The above code shows an ugly Error Alert using the normal window alert. If you want a better error like this:

[image: preview]

You can use the following code, by setting a state:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([{ name: "Arto Hellas" }]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (persons.find((p) => p.name === newName)) {
      setError(true);
      return false;
    }
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName
    };
    setPersons([...persons, nameObject]);
  };

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setNewName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName}>
        {error && <p className="error">User already exists.</p>}
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {persons.map((person) => (
        <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And here's our `style.css`:

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-tree-wsou2?file=/src/App.js**

Answer (score 1):

First add field to check name exists or not:

```
const nameExists = React.useMemo(() => {
    return persons.some(item => item.name === newName);
  }, [newName, persons])
```

Then disable button and show message if name exists:

```
<div>
          {nameExists && <p>Name {newName} already exists!</p>}
          <button type="submit" disabled={nameExists} >add</button>
        </div>
```

Also, make sure you clear name when you add new name:

```
const addName = (event) => { 
      ... 
      setNewName('')
  }
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = React.useState([  { name: 'Arto Hellas' }]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = React.useState('')

  const addName = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const nameObject = {
          name: newName,
      }
      setPersons([...persons,nameObject]);
      
      setNewName('')
  }

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
      setNewName(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const nameExists = React.useMemo(() => {
    return persons.some(item => item.name === newName);
  }, [newName, persons])
 

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName} >
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          {nameExists && <p>Name {newName} already exists!</p>}
          <button type="submit" disabled={nameExists} >add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
        {persons.map(person => (
            <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
        ))}
        
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method to search for a person with the `newName`. Please check the below code-snippet:

```js
const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const nameObject = {
        name: newName,
    }
    let personAlreadyExists = persons.find(person => person.name === newName);

    if (personAlreadyExists) {
        alert('Person with that name already exists');
        // any other operations (like clearing user input in the form, etc..)
    }
    else {
        setPersons([...persons, nameObject])
    }
}
```

[Code-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kapitsa-hbbev?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Do not add empty sandbox links